# writing to an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Example
{
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
} ExampleStruct;

void derp(struct Example * bar[], uint8_t i)
{
    uint8_t c;
    for(c = 0; c < i; ++c)
    {
        bar[c]->a = 1;
        bar[c]->b = 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Example * foo;
    uint8_t i = 3;
    foo = malloc(i*sizeof(ExampleStruct));
    derp(&foo, i);
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

I get segfaults and all debuggers tell me that code stopped working due to

```
bar[c]->a = 1;
```

I tried to rearrange this into all of the following

```
(*bar)[c]->a = 1;
(*bar[c])->a = 1;
bar[c].a = 1;
(*bar)[c].a = 1;
```

and with no success. What am I doing wrong? I don't understand why is this failing, and I don't understand why the addresses of bar[0], bar[1] and bar[2] are so far away from each other, when each just takes 2 bytes.

Comment: Change it to `struct Example* bar` and `derp(foo, i)` and `bar[c].a`. That's all. Why do you pass the address of the pointer? You don't need to change the pointer. only the elements in the array.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you're passing foo by-address *besides* the function being called  (which I assume you also wrote) requires it? If so, then do what Acme's answer suggests. If not, then do what Elazar's comment suggests. Without one or the other, you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Because I want to use foo[c].a and foo[c].b somewhere else in main

Comment: I can't see how it matters. The answer I gave initializes the array you have allocated in `main()`.

Comment: @JohnSmith - The point is not if you want to use it in main. The real question is do you want (or have a reason) to allocate an array of `struct example` objects? Because you can still pass a static object in your function `derp` and access  it in main.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I think you are afraid of copying your array. Rest assured, the only thing copied is the address of its first element.

Comment: Yes only the base address is copied, whether static or dynamic, if you are creating the object in `main` itself in both cases its never gonna make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Some changes were required since you were trying to pass array of objects:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
typedef struct Example
{
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
} ExampleStruct;

void derp(struct Example * bar[], uint8_t i)
{
    uint8_t c;
    for(c = 0; c < i; ++c)
    {
        bar[c]->a = 1;
        bar[c]->b = 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Example * foo[3];
    uint8_t i = 3, c;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    foo[i] = malloc(sizeof(ExampleStruct));
    derp(foo, i);
    for(c = 0; c < i; ++c)
    {
        printf("\n%" PRIu16  " %" PRIu16 ,foo[c]->a,foo[c]->b);
    }
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   free(foo[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

`struct Example * foo;` can hold a single pointer to an object of type `struct Example`. While `struct Example * bar[]` can hold an array of pointers to objects  of type `struct Example`.

In your original program, this will seg fault when `c` is greater than `0` since you did not allocate any pointers to an object of type `struct Example`.

```
bar[c]->a = 1;
bar[c]->b = 2;
```

For static objects:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
typedef struct Example
{
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
} ExampleStruct;

void derp(struct Example  bar[], uint8_t i)
{
    uint8_t c;
    for(c = 0; c < i; ++c)
    {
        bar[c].a = 1;
        bar[c].b = 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Example  foo[3];
    uint8_t i = 3, c;
    derp(foo, i);
    for(c = 0; c < i; ++c)
    {
        printf("\n%" PRIu16  " %" PRIu16 ,foo[c].a,foo[c].b); //accessing in main
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your suggestion complicates things for no reason. The OP wants to work with an array of structs. The pointer-to-pointer thing is part of the problem, not part of the solution.

Comment: So why should the answer be downvoted when there is nothing wrong in it. It all depends how we understand the question, i wanted to give a solution which would fix OP's code without too many changes. The question is about `writing to an array of structs` - and that could also be done with pointers.

Comment: "This answer is not useful". However, @WhozCraig explained why it may be useful in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to pass `&foo`. Keep it simple:

```
// In a function declaration, it's (almost) always a pointer, not an array.
// "struct Example bar[]" means *exactly* the same thing in this context.
void init(struct Example * bar, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        bar[i].a = 1;
        bar[i].b = 2;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    struct Example * foo = malloc(n*sizeof(struct Example));
    init(foo, n); // passes the address of the array - &a[0] - to init
    printf("The second element is {%u, %u}\n", foo[1].a, foo[1].b);
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> The second element is {1, 2}

Comment: Ah! now i get your point!! Crap!! Sorry about the misunderstanding.